# Book about a girl who gets a substance in her that gives her really strange powers

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space

There was this book I read a few years ago.

It was about a girl who gets this substance in her that gives her really strange powers. Like one is the ability to pick up any item, study it for a moment, and then she knows how it works and how to use it. There are aliens who have staffs that fire lasers and are coded to each alien who uses it by a kind of bacteria or something.

The story begins with the girl being transported to a relative. The guy taking her there is an old friend of her mother's and is either still a spice runner or an ex-spice runner. (I'm not talking about *Dune*.) As he's taking her to the city her relative is at, a spaceship crashes through the road and they fall through the hole made by the ship down to the land below, which is kinda like a slum, full of trash and piles of scrap and such.

I think the book was released sometime in 2017, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spice+runner%22&sxsrf=APwXEdfgpuJ6IJ1Zi8eYuTabAR-1Ck8HAA%3A1683832144874&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2016%2Ccd_max%3A2018&tbm=bks - I can't find anything from 2017 with "spice runner" in it